# Angular 4 Animations boolean triggers

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

I'm testing a simple fade in/fade out animation on a button using Angular 4 Animations. The issue I'm having is that because I'm using boolean values nothing is being triggered. From the dev tools it looks like an `.ng-animating` class is added to the element but nothing is changed.

This is a sample of the code I have:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'fade-btn-test',
    styles: [
        require('./fade-btn-test.component.scss')
    ],
    template: `
        <button [@test]="isActive" (click)="isActive = !isActive">My Button</button>
    `,
    animations: [
        trigger('test', [
            state('true', style({ opacity: 0 })),
            state('false', style({ opacity: 1 })),
            transition('0 <=> 1', animate(500))
        ])
    ]
})

export class FadeBtnTestComponent {
    isActive: boolean = false;
}
```

I know that the above code used to work with Angular 2, however in this case it's not working. The only solution I've found is to work using a `string` instead of a `boolean`.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'fade-btn-test',
    styles: [
        require('./fade-btn-test.component.scss')
    ],
    template: `
        <button [@test]="isActive.toString()" (click)="isActive = !isActive">My Button</button>
    `,
    animations: [
        trigger('test', [
            state('true', style({ opacity: 0 })),
            state('false', style({ opacity: 1 })),
            transition('true <=> false', animate(500))
        ])
    ]
})

export class FadeBtnTestComponent {
    isActive: boolean = false;
}
```

From the above code you will note that the animation trigger `@test` is reading a string (`isActive.toString()`) and the `transition` function has `true <=> false` passed instead of `0 <=> 1`.

Although I got it to work I'm not sure if there was any update to the Animation module itself. Is anyone aware of any changes to the Animation module with the Angular 4 update?

Comment: have you read the changelog?

Comment: Yep, couldn't find anything related to this though

Comment: I could not find anything else in the change log either, but it seems that true false is no longer supported without your workaround. If you dont want to use .toString() you can just make your state 0 or 1 instead of true or false.

Comment: Yeah it seems that it's not supported anymore, for now I'll use the workaround. I prefer to work with a boolean in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use string values instead of Boolean values, and change the value of states accordingly:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'fade-btn-test',
    styles: [
        require('./fade-btn-test.component.scss')
    ],
    template: `
        <button [@test] = "value" (click)="isActive = !isActive">My Button</button>
    `,
    animations: [
        trigger('test', [
            state('active', style({ opacity: 0 })),
            state('inactive', style({ opacity: 1 })),
            transition('active <=> inactive', animate(500))
        ])
    ]
})

export class FadeBtnTestComponent {
    value: string= 'active';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Angular changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/56b751ead5407a3a0d9258599516cbe859030956/CHANGELOG.md#400-rc6-2017-03-23), transition boolean values bug was fixed in 4.0.0-rc6 (check [PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15311)).

However, the mixed syntax supported in Angular 2 is not working anymore. Boolean values must be used in both state definition and transition expression as in the sample below:

```
export const ANIMATION_SAMPLE = trigger('booleanTrigger', [
    state('1', style({ ...})),
    state('0', style({ ...})),
    transition('1 => 0', animate(...)),
    transition('0 => 1', animate(...))
]);
```

[This answer comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340919/angular-2-animation-boolean-trigger?rq=1#comment73834044_40480481) suggests the same workaround to work with boolean triggers.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug which was reported here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15247
and was fixed with this PR: 
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15311